# Appending file name of combined excel file data into master sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file that uses VBA to take all excel files in a directory (all files have the same structure/headings) and combines them all into the new excel file starting in column B.

[image]

What I can't figure out is how to take the file name of each file as it is opened and place that name in column A for every row that just had data appended to it. Please help.

```
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim path As String
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Dim rowCount As String
Dim myRange As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'change folder path of excel files here
path = InputBox("Enter the path to the folder containing the excel files you want to combine.", "Excel Combiner")
Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder(path)
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

'Grab filename from each open file
Dim MyName As String
MyName = everyObj.Name


'change "A2" with cell reference of start point for every files here
'for example "B3:IV" to merge all files start from columns B and rows 3
'If you're files using more than IV column, change it to the latest column
'Also change "A" column on "A65536" to the same column as start point
Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Activate

'Do not change the following column. It's not the same column as above
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Paste scan name into Column A
NEED SOMETHING HERE
```

Comment: When you open the file to dump the data, just do a quick `filename=book.name` then drop `filename` into column A. Declare `filename` as type string.

Comment: I've gotten to that point. The problem I'm having is that the file name should only apply to the data that was pasted from the workbook that is being imported at that moment.

Comment: Huh. So you're not doing this via a loop?

Comment: I am using a loop to read each files contents and add them to the main workbook, but I need each filename to only apply to column A for each workbooks data when it is imported. 

Please see new image uploaded into main post.

Comment: Uhhh then my idea works. It would help to see code for your loop because you must be doing something funny XD

Comment: Please see uploaded code.

Comment: So do `filename=booklist.name` Guess you have trouble determining how many rows eh? So create a new variable that finds lastrow then use it in place of `Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row` as well as when you paste.

Comment: How do you find the lastrow?

Comment: Sigh. You don't understand your code at all do you XD Edit: I have essentially given you a guide leaving out some details for you to discover. Please study your code. I will upvote since you have shown effort and appears you will continue to do so but I am not the type to spoon feed XD

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for the file name you can use .Name property of the workbook object, but it does give you the file extension as well though. If you want the full file path you can use the .Path property of the workbook object. Once you do one of those you can just assign the value to the cell as you get them or store them all up in an array and output them to the column in one go.